# Angular Material Date Picker - disable dates based on external API call

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material, momentjs

I'm using an external API to return all the bank holidays. I need to use this response to disable all these dates in the Angular Material date picker (as well as weekends).

Because i'm making a HTTP call it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my latest code but this currently just disables all dates:

```
onDisableDates = (date: any) => {
    const day = date.day();

    this.validationService.getBankHolidayDates().subscribe(response => {
      const bankHolidays = response['england-and-wales'].events.map(i => new Date(i.date));
      bankHolidays.forEach(bankHoliday => {
        let isBankHoliday = false;
        const holiday = bankHoliday.toLocaleDateString();
        const input = moment(new Date(date)).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

        if (holiday === input) {
          isBankHoliday = true;
        }

        return day !== 0 && day !== 6 && !isBankHoliday;
     });
   });
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-label>
  <input id="startDate" matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="onDisableDates" [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="minDate" formControlName="startDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Also, please note that im using MAT_DATE_LOCALE and the MomentDateAdapter.

Any guidance would be great as its taken me days trying to get this to work!

Stackblitz here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvqzpb-u9d52c

Comment: i would be happy to help you. can you create a stackblitz for it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvqzpb-u9d52c

Answer (score 2):

I have done some editing in your stackblitz demo. You can have look into it

**component code ::**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';
import moment, * as moments from 'moment';  
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Datepicker with filter validation */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-filter-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerFilterExample {
startDate = new Date();
guestForm:any;
  constructor(private validationService: ValidationService,private fb:FormBuilder) {

  // this.myGroup = this.fb.group({
  //   startDate: ['',],
  //   // enter the other form controls in the group

  // });
  this.guestForm = new FormGroup({
startDate: new FormControl()
});
  }

  onDisableDates = (date: any) => {
    const day = date.getDay ();
    this.validationService.getBankHolidayDates().subscribe(response => {

      const bankHolidays = response['england-and-wales'].events.map(i => new Date(i.date));
      bankHolidays.forEach(bankHoliday => {
        let isBankHoliday = false;
        const holiday = bankHoliday.toLocaleDateString();
        const input = moment(new Date(bankHoliday)).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

        if (holiday === input) {
          isBankHoliday = true;
        }
      });
    });

    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }
}
```

**HTML code ::**

```
<form [formGroup]="guestForm" novalidate>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-label>
  <input id="startDate" matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="onDisableDates" [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="minDate" formControlName="startDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**and got output like this ::**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aarsh, but what i'm looking to do is exclude the dates that are served up from the service (as well as weekends). I have used a local json file instead now called data.json so you can see what i mean. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvqzpb-u9d52c - hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that was struggling with this (like me)... the key was first to enable binding in the HTML using this -

```
[matDatepickerFilter]="onDisableDates.bind(this)"
```

This then meant that I could 'pre-load' the data on the page load and then use that data to disable the dates required when the date picker was used, like so :

```
bankHolidays: any;

constructor(private validationService: ValidationService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.validationService.getBankHolidayDates().subscribe(response => {
    this.bankHolidays = response['england-and-wales'].events.map(i =>
      moment(new Date(i.date)).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
  });
}

onDisableDates(date: any): boolean {
  const day = date.day();
  const input = moment(new Date(date)).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  return !this.bankHolidays.includes(input) && day !== 0 && day !== 6;
}
```

Hope this helps someone save time :)

Comment: if you write your function like onDisableDates=(date:any)=>{...} you needn't use 'bind'